# Creating a shop/ item system in flutter with SQL, how to structure in-game/app items properly?

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, sqflite

New to SQL & databases, creating an in-app shop that holds different items.

```
  void _createTableItems(Batch batch) {
    batch.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Items');
    batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE boughtItems ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    price INTEGER
  )''');
  }

class Item {
  Item({required this.id, required this.price, required this.title});
  String title;
  int id;
  int price;
}


List<Item> availableProducts = [WeaponItem(id: 0, strength: 5), WeaponItem(id: 1, strength: 7), StableItem(id: 2, speed: 4), FoodItem(id: 3, rev: 7)]
```

I pretty much have the most basic strucutre possible right now.
When I need to get the products, all I do is search the availableProducts list of items for ID's in the database query.

```
  Future<List<Item>> getBought() async {
await database;

List products = await _database!.query("Items");

List<Item> result = [];

for (var element in products) {
  result.add(availableProducts.where((e) => e.id == element["id"]).first);
}

return result;
```

}

Is this an acceptable way to do this?

What I'm worried about is the mixing of item types.

I'm a bit lost since there's multiple things I could do. Should I create a different table holding all the properties of each individual items? Should I add a type string to the table   to differentiate the different items?

Answer (score 0):

I would create one table for example products. This table
has general information about the products(id, name, product_number, info) that all products have in common. If you want additional and different information for every product type, I would add a fk_type which references to a product_type(id, name) table that stores the different product types. Then I would create an additional table for every product type. Ex: product_weapon(id, size, ammunition, reload_time ), product_chair(id, high, depth, weight). But you can also work just with the simple product table and add general description fields that could store jsons, xmls, css files.